# Why does GoogleApiClient successfully connects even if I don't provide it with an account?

Tags: android, authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to implement Google Sign-In in my Android app.

Here's my code:

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

}
```

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) guide, attempting to connect when the user is not signed in should result in an onConnectionFailed callback. However, this code always displays "CONNECTED" toast, even though I never authorize the app.

What exactly am I misunderstanding? How am I supposed to check if the user is signed in, if this method doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

When onConnected method invoke it doesn't mean that the `User is signed in`. It means that mGoogleApiCLient has connected.

After this callback, the application can make requests on other methods provided by the client.

You can take [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#public-methods) from here.

Comment: Okay, then, how do I check if the user is signed in or not?